# Цепочка iptables для web-сервера

Tags: linux, iptables

Доброго времени суток!
Прошу совета по настройке iptables web-сервера.

1. Web-сервер работает на 80 и 443 портах.
2. Коннект с базой (На другом сервере) по портам 3306 и 5432.
3. Сервер подключен к vpn.
4. Сервер отправляет письма noreply через sendmail.
5. eth1 - интернет
6. eth2 - DMZ
7. tap0 - VPN сеть

Собственно, вопрос:

Можно ли обойтись без --sport 443, 80 e.t.c. -j ACCEPT?

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]

:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth2 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 5432 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth2 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -s ip_Офиса/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth1 -s 8.8.8.8 -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth1 -d 8.8.8.8 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp -m udp --sport 1194 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i tap0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth1 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i tap0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i eth2 -p icmp -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -i tap0 -j DROP

-A INPUT -i eth1 -j DROP

-A INPUT -i eth2 -j DROP
```

Благодарю за внимание и понимание!

Answer (score 1):

Можно, если на хосте нет других сервисов и нет уязвимости в исполнении кода веб приложений которые могли бы устанавливать новые соединения.